# Add navigation bar to a view controller without a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, interface-builder

How do you add a navigation bar to a view controller (collection view controller, actually) that is not embedded in a navigation controller? I tried dragging a Navigation Bar onto the view, but it's just not sticking. This is in Swift.

Comment: I guess Xcode won't let you do this but try to insert it via code, it should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try putting this code in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
let height: CGFloat = 75
let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: height))
navbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navbar.delegate = self

let navItem = UINavigationItem()
navItem.title = "Title"
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)

navbar.items = [navItem]

view.addSubview(navbar)

collectionView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - height))
```

`height` can, of course, be anything you want. And the actions for the `UIBarButton`s are selectors to whatever function you want. (You also don't need to have buttons at all).

**Edits:**

1. Adjusted the `collectionView`'s frame so it would not overlap with `UINavigationBar`.
2. Made height a constant so all its references can be changed in one place.

Comment: Ok, so this can't be done via the interface builder right?

Comment: @Prabhu it may be possible if you use a regular `UIViewController`, extend it to `UICollectionViewDataSource` `UICollectionViewDelegate`, and then drag a collectionView into it rather than using the default `UICollectionViewController` class and IB Object.

Answer (score 3):

Here is version for swift 5.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(toolbar)
    toolbar.delegate = self
    
    let height: CGFloat = 75
    let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height))
    navbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navbar.delegate = self

    let navItem = UINavigationItem()
    navItem.title = "Title"
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)

    navbar.items = [navItem]

    view.addSubview(navbar)

    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height))
    
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Swift 4:

```
private func addNavigationBar() {
    let height: CGFloat = 75
    var statusBarHeight: CGFloat = 0
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        statusBarHeight = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
    } else {
        statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    }
    let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: statusBarHeight, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height))
    navbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navbar.delegate = self as? UINavigationBarDelegate

    let navItem = UINavigationItem()
    navItem.title = "Sensor Data"
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissViewController))

    navbar.items = [navItem]

    view.addSubview(navbar)

    self.view?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height - height))
}
```

Comment: How to force all other GUI elements go down for the chosen height?

Comment: @Passe, he changed view's frame. All your subviews must be pinned to top of parent view.